# SmartGWT TextItem add style dynamically

Tags: css, smartgwt

I need add a "line-height" value to my TextItem object in DynamicForm after i calculate it. I can't do it like this myTextItem.getElement.getStyle... Someone can help me ?

Comment: Providing some actual code would help.

Comment: I just create TextItem objecy add style to it (object.setTextBoxStyle(style)) and now i calculate hat height I need. When I have this value I want add to my style "line-height" with my calculated height.

Comment: line-height is the distance between lines.. Are you sure your don't want to use a TextAreaItem instead?

Comment: I'm sure that I want use TextItem with line-height style parameter